# Does the volume of solution increase during a neutralisation reaction?

Tags: acid-base

Say I mixed together 20 mL of HCl solution with 20 mL of NaOH solution.

$$\ce{HCl (aq) + NaOH (aq) -> NaCl + H2O}$$

Strictly speaking, would the water produced from the neutralisation process cause the volume of the overall mixture to slightly increase? So, would the volume of the final mixture (strictly speaking) be 40 mL + the volume of water produced from the reaction?

Comment: Yes but, a quick calculation shows that using 0.1M solutions, which is relatively strong for many applications, the amount of water produced would be 0.036g of water, which is less than 0.1% of the initial volume.  This is in the same order as the thermal expansion of about 10 degree temperature rise at roughly room temperature. Does that context help?

Comment: @spontification why not just write an answer? :)

Comment: The volume may change slightly, but not for that reason. After all, these water molecules did not appear out of thin air. Instead, they formed from some particles ($\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$) that were in the the initial solutions and certainly _did_ occupy some volume there.

Comment: a good question to me, I think I felt I would be making more out of the question than is actually there. Strictly speaking the answer to the OP is "yes" but my comment was "practically speaking this is almost always irrelevant".

Answer (score 1):

Let consider an example:

According to [one supplier](https://www.fishersci.com/shop/products/hydrochloric-acid-solution-volumetric-1m-hcl-1n-honeywell-fluka/60047399), at 20 degrees Celsius, $1$ Molar $\ce{HCl}$ has a density of $1.010\ g / cm^3$

According to [another supplier](https://www.merckmillipore.com/GB/en/product/Sodium-hydroxide-solution-1-mol-L,MDA_CHEM-137031), at 20 degrees Celsius, $1$ Molar $\ce{NaOH}$ has a density of $1.04\ g / cm^3$

From Wikipedia (note the $1\ mg$ / $1$ part in 10000 error in mass conservation)
1 mole of $\ce{NaOH}$ weighs $39.997\ g$
1 mole of $\ce{HCl}$ weighs $36.46\ g$
1 mole of $\ce{NaCl}$ weighs $58.443\ g$
1 mole of $\ce{H2O}$ weighs $18.015\ g$

Mixing 1 litre of each solution to make 1 mole of $\ce{NaCl}$:

Going in:

Base:

- $\ce{NaOH}$ : $39.997\ g$
- $\ce{H20}$ : $1040 (\pm 10) - 39.997 = 1000 \pm 10g$

Acid:

- $\ce{HCl}$ : $36.46\ g$
- $\ce{H2O}$ : $1010 (\pm 1) - 36.46 = 974 \pm 1 g$

Result:

- $\ce{NaCl}$ : $58.443\ g$
- $\ce{H2O}$ : $1000 (\pm 10) + 974 (\pm 1)+ 18.105 = 1990 \pm 10 g$

The percentage by mass of $\ce{NaCl}$ is
$$
\frac{58.443}{58.443 + 1990 \pm 10} = 2.85 \pm 0.02 \%
$$

Feeding that percentage mass in to [chemical engineering tables](https://www.handymath.com/cgi-bin/nacltble.cgi?submit=Entry)
the density is given as $1.0183 \pm 0.0002 \ g / cm^3$ at 20 degrees Celcius.
This is very similar to the $1.020\ g/cm^{-3}$ [density given by a supplier](https://www.fishersci.co.uk/shop/products/sodium-hydroxide-solution-volumetric-0-5m-naoh-0-5n-honeywell-fluka-3/15604900) of $0.5$ M $\ce{NaCl}$

This gives a final volume of
$$
\frac{2050 \pm 10}{1.0183 \pm 0.0002} = 2010 \pm 10 cm^3
$$

**So this particular case is likely to be a very small amount larger in volume** than the original two solutions, but this balance is **going to depend** on atmospheric pressure, temperature, and the specific acid and base used in the neutralization and their salt.

Comment: It is a pity you took a poor precision in the initial density of $\ce{NaOH 1 M}$. With your choice ($1.04 g/mL$}, the uncertainty is ±$1$% :  the final result has a large uncertainty : $2010 ± 10 cm^3$. So it looks as if there is no volume change. If you had opened the Handbook of Physics and Chemistry, you would have found the value $1.0433$ for the density of $\ce{NaOH 1 M}$. As a consequence, the final volume of mixture would have been $2010 ± 1 mL$. And indeed I have often made the mixture $\ce{HCl 1 M + NaOH 1M}$ in my classroom. I can state that the volume increase is quite visible.

Answer (score 0):

> Say I mixed together 20 mL of HCl solution with 20 mL of NaOH solution.
> $$\ce{HCl (aq) + NaOH (aq) -> NaCl + H2O}$$

You are not telling us the concentrations of the two solutions, so the answer will be conceptual rather than quantitative.

> Strictly speaking, would the water produced from the neutralisation process cause the volume of the overall mixture to slightly increase?

The water from the neutralisation would contribute to the total volume. As Ivan Neretin said in the comments, there would also be a loss of hydronium and hydroxide ions.

> So, would the volume of the final mixture (strictly speaking) be 40 mL + the volume of water produced from the reaction?

Strictly speaking, any reaction in solution will change the volume of the solution (except when the reaction is "symmetrical" or by rare coincidence). The direction of change depends whether the volume-averaged density of the two components you are mixing is larger or smaller than the density of the final solution. If all components are dilute aqueous solutions, the volume change will be hard to detect because it is so small.